# Send data to modules in IoT edge - Azure IoT Edge

Tags: java, azure-iot-edge

I just started learning Azure IoT edge. My question is once I create a custom java module how do I communicate with it from my local spring server so that I can send it data. I have tried using ModuleClient Object by using the module's connectionString. What I noticed was data was getting sent directly to edgeHub rather than through my module.
According to my knowledge Routes are only used for module to module and module to edgeHub communication. So I just want to know if there are other ways in which I can send data to my module.

I have used the below code snippet.

```
String connString = " ";

IotHubClientProtocol protocol = IotHubClientProtocol.AMQPS;
Message messageToSendFromDeviceToModule =  new Message("lorem ipsum.......");
ModuleClient moduleClient = new ModuleClient(connString ,protocol);
moduleClient.open();
moduleClient.sendEventAsync(messageToSendFromDeviceToModule ,null ,null);
System.out.println("MESSAGE SENT");
Thread.sleep(1000);
moduleClient.closeNow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating my answer after some more context was added in the comments. You mentioned you wanted to know how you could send data to the custom module made through [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-java-module?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-2020-11).

Azure IoT Edge modules can receive communication in a couple of ways:

1. Direct methods
2. Module twin updates
3. Module to module messages
4. Exposing their own API (custom built)

The tutorial that you linked, creates a Java module that supports listening to module twin updates, **and only that**. When you have deployed this module to a device, you can use the Service SDK or [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/modules/update-twin?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) to update the edge module. I don't know if this is available in the [Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/tree/main), but it is in C#, Python, C and Node.js
If you're not deployed to a device yet, and want to debug your module first, you can [set up the Azure IoT Edge simulator through a device connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module?view=iotedge-2020-11?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#set-up-iot-edge-simulator). Follow option 1 (copied here):

> Option 1: simulate an IoT Edge solution:
>
> In the **Explorer** tab on the left side, expand the **Azure IoT Hub**
> section. Right-click on your IoT Edge device ID, and then select **Setup**
> **IoT Edge Simulator** to start the simulator with the device connection
> string. You can see the IoT Edge Simulator has been successfully set
> up by reading the progress detail in the integrated terminal.

This will create a module in Azure IoT Hub called `target`, you can use the same SDK and REST API linked above to update the module twin.

*If you wanted to use module-to-module communication, I'll leave my original answer in:*
If you want to send data to the input(s) of your custom module, you should consider running the IoT Edge Simulator. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module?view=iotedge-2020-11?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#set-up-iot-edge-simulator) for more information on how to do that. This approach will create a testing utility container that can relay HTTP requests to your module's input. You can specify the output in the request, sample below (from the linked documentation):

```sh
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"inputName": "input1","data":"hello world"}' http://localhost:53000/api/v1/messages
```

Comment: I wanted to know how i can send the data to module via api

Comment: What API do you mean? Are you exposing an API in your module? Are you trying to do this through IoT Hub?

Comment: For example I have developed a custom java module with which I want to communicate and send data from my local spring server how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm afraid more context is needed, you might need to update your question too. Have you built an API in your module? By what means does your custom module accept incoming data?

Comment: consider the example java module in the below link, by what means can I send data to it?   [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-java-module?view=iotedge-2020-11)

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer to deal with the context of the tutorial module you linked! Please note that this module only supports 1 form of communication.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but could you please give some more information about the methods which you specified.  Also, I have tried sending data using the connection string of the module in java but it was directly going to edgeHub. It was not going through the module as expected.

Comment: If you're using the connection string, you're connecting *as* the module, not *to* the module. So that's not the way to send data to your module. I highly recommend reading the docs and possibly try Microsoft Learn to learn more about the basics, as this is pretty much getting out of StackOverflow's scope now. You can also try Microsoft Q&A to get more help what you're trying to do.